# ipad difficulties with more than one #

Tags: jquery, ipad, url-encoding

I have a url that either looks like this

http://www.URL.com/photography.html#project

or this

http://www.URL.com/photography.html#img1

or even this

http://www.URL.com/photography.html#project#img1

This is working grand on all browsers but in the iPad the URL is changed to look like this

http://www.URL.com/photography.html#project%23img1

It's not allowing my specific code to work, can i encode this second # a different way if the device is an ipad? I really don't want to start recoding a different way for ipad if I can help it.

Any ideas are more than welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: 2 functions that work differently, separately and also together. so i can't have #project/img1 cos then i might get /img1.. this was the best way

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd dig this up even though the question is already rather old. There might still be people struggling with the same topic.

---

Although the use of multiple fragment identifiers is not [explicitly illegal](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_2_Fragments.html) it seems that using more than one is against the specification as it states:

> The fragment-id follows the URL of the whole object from which it is separated by a hash sign (#).

Thus you can argue that a only a single hash sign should be present. Browsers accepting and parsing multiple characters of this type can't be relied upon becuase it is undefined behavior.

Instead I would suggest you build up your fragment identifier in a different form as you already hinted on.

```
http://www.URL.com/photography.html#project/img1
```

In this case you can use a simple expression to get the functions.

```
window.location.hash.split("/"); // yields ["project", "img1"]
```